# How to Route To a Different Page in Reactjs After Registration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I created an API that handles requests of users registering into my website, but I want the website to redirect them to the home page after they have successfully registered.

The data goes to my database and the server returns success but I don't know why it doesn't route to a different page.

Here is my code:

Signup.js

```
const submitUser = () => {

     Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/signUp', {
        title: title, 
        first_name: firstName, 
        last_name: lastName, 
        company: company, 
        phone_type: phoneType, 
        phone: phone, 
        email: email, 
        password:password,
        confirm_password:confirm_password
     })
     .then(() => {
        //go to main page
        <Route exact path="/"  component={HomeIn} />
     });
};
```

server folder
index.js:

```
app.post('/api/signUp', (req, res) => {

    const Title = req.body.title
    const fname = req.body.first_name
    const lname = req.body.last_name
    const comp = req.body.company
    const pt = req.body.phone_type
    const pn = req.body.phone
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password
    const confirm_password = req.body.confirm_password

    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users (title,first_name,last_name,email,company,phone_type,phone_number,password,confirm_password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
    db.query(sqlInsert, [Title,fname,lname,email,comp,pt,pn,password,confirm_password], (err, result) => {
       console.log("Success")
    });
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: why don't I see you sending a response back to the client?